# Where is the sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight.C as mentioned in explored?

Tags: sapui5

In the SAPUI5 control explorer in the [busy dialog section](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight/preview) there is mention of a sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight.C control. Essentially this is an unframed dialog with the busy indicator 3-blue blobs image over it. I intend to use this whilst long JSON fetches are running.

My version of OpenUI5 which is v1.40.10 does not have a file or folder with that name in the sap.m.* folders. It only has sap.m.BusyDialog.js which I read (dbg version) and see no obvious mention of a light model.

So can anyone tell me if there is actually a BusyDialogLight control and how to define it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the [controller](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.BusyDialogLight/code/C.controller.js) which handles the view. The name used there is the same as in the view's controllerName attribute. And light is in this context just the BusyDialog without text and buttons.

Comment: Ah thanks. I get it now. The 3-blob image is what you get as a dialogue if you define no other controls. There is no other dialogue control to extend. Thank you. I was trying too hard.